# IIS 10 - maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU setting over 5000 is ignored

Tags: performance, iis, load-testing, iis-10

Facing an issue on IIS 10 (Windows Server 2016, .NET 4 integrated mode, classic ASP.NET app) where `maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU` setting of over 5000 does not seem to be applied. However setting it to lower values has clear and visible effect.

I'm using JMetter for load testing. If I set thread count to 5000, I see 100% success rate, but anything higher has failure rates regardless of how high I set `maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU` and `requestQueueLimit`. For example testing with 6000 threads consistently renders 16.6% failure rate.

If I set `maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU` to something low like 12, I get almost 99% failure rate, so I know the lower bound settings have effect, just not anything over 5000.

The VM has 2 cores assigned, so with 5000 x 2 cores I feel I should be able to successfully test with 10,000 threads.

#### Aspnet.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.web> 
        <applicationPool 
           maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="50000" 
           maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0" 
           requestQueueLimit="50000"/> 
    </system.web>

    <runtime>
        <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="false" />
        <legacyImpersonationPolicy enabled="true"/>
        <alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy enabled="false"/>
        <SymbolReadingPolicy enabled="1" />
        <shadowCopyVerifyByTimestamp enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" />
</configuration>
```

## What could be overwriting these settings and enforcing the upper bound of 5000?

I feel there is some additional setting that needs to be set to exceed 5000.

Any help / advice would be appreciated at this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into something similar, and after some digging, I believe the setting you're looking for is in the site configuration, called [appConcurrentRequestLimit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/iis/configuration/system.webserver/serverruntime). I was able to test lower limits work as expected, but I don't have a good way to test over 5000 connections at the moment. I will update this post if/when I hit > 5000 connections in the future.

**Update:** Can confirm that this setting did the trick.

To change this value:

1. Click on the site in the left pane of IIS Manager.
2. Double-click Configuration Editor in the right pane.
3. From the "Section" dropdown, choose "system.webServer/serverRuntime".
4. Set the appConcurrentRequestLimit value (default is 5000).
5. Click "Apply" in the Actions pane.
6. Restart the site.

Comment: Thanks for replying to this dated post. Would have to check if that setting is available. Curious what ver of .net / WinServ / iis you tried on. To load test, I recommend using JMeter (https://jmeter.apache.org/), there are quick examples around on google.

Comment: Following up to confirm this did indeed work. This was on Windows Server 2016.

Comment: @Keith How to set those on linux ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to execute more than 5000 requests concurrently, you'll need to increase the requestQueueLimit. The requestQueueLimit restricts the total number of requests in the system. Due to its legacy, it is actually the total number of requests in the system, and not the number of requests in some queue. It's goal is to prevent the server from toppling over due to lack of physical memory, virtual memory, etc. When the limit is reached, incoming requests will receive a quick 503 "Server Too Busy" response.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I was actually aware of that, so if you see in my example above I used 50,000 for both requestQueueLimit and maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU, but for some reason I could not go above 5000.So my guess there is another setting somewhere enforcing this limit.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other way to enforce this limit.

Answer (score 0):

just try to set appConcurrentRequestLimit over 5000